# Javascript function returns value.call another function according to first functions return value

Tags: javascript, callback, synchronous

sorry this might not be new question but i am new to JS and i didnt get any specific examples for this.

```
function find(param){            
        $.each(array,function(i,elem){              
            if(elem.id==param){
                return i;
            }
        })
        return null;
    }
//after calling this function i want to perform actions based on result
$(document).on("click","#elem",function(){
      //want to make this part synchronous
      $.when(i=find(param1)).then(function{
      if(i==null)
          {//do something
          }
      else{//do something
          }
})
}
```

i want to perform actions based on return value of find function.and also the conditions should only be checked ater the find function is over.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do?  Right now I really don't understand what this is _meant_ to do.

Comment: That's about it. You can get clever with assignment inside a conditional, but what you have is the basic pattern—assign the return value, test it, then do something based on the result.

Comment: i edited the code for what it exactly does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your find function will always return null.

```
$.each(array,function(i,elem){              
    if(elem.id==param){
        return i;   //this is each iteration callback scope not find function scope
    }
})
```

The find function should look like this:

```
function find(param){
    var matched=null;            
    $.each(array,function(i,elem){              
        if(elem.id==param){
            matched=i;
        }
    })
    return matched;
}
```

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: thanks.this explained my why i could not get expected results.

Comment: i was doing the callbacks right. this was the actual problem. @Chickenrice thanks.